# Custom ordering of string values in LINQ-to-SQL query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have an `IQueryable<...>` object that is a LINQ-to-SQL query that I am trying to order by name in alphabetical order, but with the numbers after letters (a-z,0-9 instead of 0-9,a-z). For example, the list:

```
1st Street
Zeta
2nd Street
Alpha
```

Should be ordered as:

```
Alpha
Zeta
1st Street
2nd Street
```

Currently I have the following code:

```
IQueryable<...> holdings = ...;
/* ... */
return holdings.OrderBy(q => q.Name);
```

But this orders the items as follows:

```
1st Street
2nd Street
Alpha
Zeta
```

Any thoughts on how to order this `IQueryable` in the desired manner?

Comment: Provide your own `IComparer` and use [that overload of `OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549422(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Also, is this comparison case-sensitive?  Or does it only handle English letters vs numbers?

Comment: @ryanyuyu He's using `Queryable.OrderBy` not `Enumerable.OrderBy`, so that's not really an option.

Comment: @Servy my mistake on the documentation link.  There is an [overload for IQueryables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534863(v=vs.100).aspx) as well.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Case is not really a concern as for this OrderBy: `A` and `a` can be treated inter-changeably.

Comment: @ryanyuyu The query provider isn't going to be able to meaningfullly translate that comparer into whatever querying mechanism it uses on the underlying data source.  For example, if the `IQueryable` represents an EF query to a SQL based database, there's no real way to convert that comparer into SQL code.  The provider is only ever going to ignore it, or throw an error saying it's not supported.

Comment: @JamesC.TaylorIV What is the actual provider of the `IQueryable` query?  Is it an EF query?  LINQ-to-SQL?  NHibernate?  Something else?

Comment: @Servy the query uses LINQ-to-SQL, and the casting type is a custom object, where the only Property used in the order is the `string Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work, with the caveat that you'll need to modify your object's class or create a new [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

It essentially puts a space character before any name that doesn't start with a number, then orders on that. Spaces are usually sorted before numbers in SQL ordering.

```
holdings.Select(h => new {
    name = h.name,

    /* copy all other fields you need here */

    // select a new field specifically for ordering.
    orderingName = SqlMethods.Like(q.name, "[^0-9]%") ? " " + q.name : q.name
}).OrderBy(q => q.orderingName);
```

I'm pretty sure there are some serious performance issues that may arise because of the `CASE` statement this will generate. You can probably solve the problem better by pre-computing the sort name ahead of time and just storing it in the database and then sorting and indexing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are willing to give up the `Iqueryable` part, you can do a `.ToList()` and do the rest in memory.

The other option I see would be to do a double orderby:

First Orderby() descending on the first character
Second ThenBy() on the entire name